# AngularJS tutorial isn't reading expressions

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do the AngularJS tutorial here for v1.2.12, and what I'm getting on my localhost is much different from the live demo they have on the tutorial itself.

Mainly, just starting with the first couple steps, it is not reading my expressions. They are just there in plain text, like they're cut and paste out of the code.

For instance in step 0, my local host is giving me

Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}

while the live demo on the site gives

Nothing here yet!

The same seems to happen for other steps. For some reason step #1 works just like it does on the webpage.

What's up with this? Did I forget to install some part of Angular? Or what? Is the tutorial just messed up?

Here's an example of the code that still does it wrong:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <!--Sidebar content-->

        Search: <input ng-model="query">
        Sort by:
        <select ng-model="orderProp">
          <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
          <option value="age">Newest</option>
        </select>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <!--Body content-->

        <ul class="phones">
          <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
            <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I used git checkout -f step-5 for this one, and instead of giving me a long list of phones like it does in the demo, I just see {{phone.name}} and {{phone.snippet}} when I run index.html on a local server.

Comment: Any console errors? Did you add ng-app to your html tag?

Comment: Could you at least post your code?

Comment: Uh really? I "am criticizing the tutorials"? The code is exactly as the tutorials say, and it does the same thing at multiple steps even though I use the "git checkout -f step-#". I am just trying to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Answered!

The NPM install was not allowing bower to do the proper installs.

This was fixed by installing Bower globally, and executing "bower install" from the command line while in the proper directory that the tutorial is saved in.

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are missing something. All basic angular tutorials works. Unfortunately without code its impossible to give a real reason. We can only guess that:

1. You are not including properly angularjs.js files, and angular cant bootstrap Your code.
2. You are trying to run Your html locally straight via browser by opening html file, not by serving it by any server instance (like apache or nodejs).

Such solution will not work whrn including scripts because of some safety restrictions. Use a server, or instead linking script file from disk, try using CDN angular links.

3 . Your angular code is wrong.

Comment: Hey, I don't know what it could be. I use git checkout -f step-#soandso, so my code is perfect just as the tutorial has it, and it still doesn't work. I'm using karma to host the local server, too. 

I had to use Karma for that one by doing "sudo npm start", because typing ./scripts/web-server.js into a new terminal window gave a bash error No Such File or Directory.

Comment: Im on phone, so i may be innacurate but... did bower install work properly? It should run automatically, but for me it once failed silently (on npm install). Try bower install and check.

Comment: You should try linking CDN angular source instead of local one and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/semijiyi/1/edit) hope this will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}
</body>
</html>
```

i think you forget to add "angular js" or ng-app directive

Comment: My code is exactly as the tutorial has it, I'm using "git checkout -f step-#soandso"

This is the tutorial -> https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/tutorial/step_00

Comment: Weirdly, the code taken from the tutorial is giving me the same thing on that demo site you posted here. But why would they give the live demo with a working version when the code itself doesn't do that?

Comment: @Femtosecond have you installed bower and "bower components", i think you are missing them.

Comment: I think I have... I did it all separately, and I did it w/ NPM install. Maybe if I do it separately, it doesn't work for some reason? Is there an order one must do it in?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing the components. Checking now!

Comment: run command "bower install angular" this will install angular in bower_component folder, hope this will help